# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not called in TableView defined in SubView defined in xib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I have been trying to create a custom view loaded through xib that contains a button and tableview. The table view is shown or hidden when button is pressed.
This interaction works and the table is created / shown. The problem I have is that I can not click on the table rows.
I have been looking all over and haven't found a solution that works.
I made sure that delegate and dataSource are set. I also do not have a GestureRecognizer for the ViewController it is used in that could absorb the touch.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing?

Here is the code of this custom view:

```
class SubUnitSpinner : UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var spinnerTableView: UITableView!
let subUnitNames: [String] = ["World", "Add/Remove"]

override init( frame: CGRect ) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    loadViewFromNib()
    setupTableView()
}

required init?( coder aDecoder: NSCoder ) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    loadViewFromNib()
    setupTableView()

}

func setupTableView() {
    spinnerTableView.delegate = self
    spinnerTableView.dataSource = self
    spinnerTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    spinnerTableView.rowHeight = 30
    spinnerTableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    spinnerTableView.allowsSelection = true
    spinnerTableView.hidden = true

}

func loadViewFromNib() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SubUnitSpinner", bundle: bundle)
    let xibView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    xibView.frame = bounds
    xibView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(xibView)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = spinnerTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")! as UITableViewCell;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.textLabel?.text = subUnitNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //Interaction
    print("cell with path: \(indexPath.row)")
}


@IBAction func spinnerTabbed(sender: AnyObject) {
    spinnerTableView.hidden = !spinnerTableView.hidden
} }
```

Update:

View Layout creation:

The xib view layout has been defined in the "storyboard" and the File's Owner set to SubUnitSpinner. The IBOutlet and IBAction where created by ctrl drag and drop.

Usage in UIViewController:

I use it as part of a UIViewController which also has been defined in the storyboard. I added a UIView and declared the Custom Class to be SubUnitSpinner. 
The SubUnitSpinner with layout as defined in xib shows up when running it and the button is clickable, the UITableView is shown / hidden when button is shown. The only thing not working is clicking on the tableView cells.

Is something wrong with the setup?

Comment: try making xibView (let xibView = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView) as a global var, and keep it (dont allow ARC to dealloc).

Comment: @RJE Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Does the view has user interaction enabled? I can see you have it enabled for UITableView but what about the container view itself?

Comment: @ManjulShrestha Yes, it is enabled from the corresponding UIViewControl. I also just added it in the class and no change.

Comment: How were you able to create IBOutlet when you class SubUnitSpinner is a subclass of UIView instead of UIViewController. Can you show how you displayed this view with your code?

Comment: @ManjulShrestha: I added an update to the questions, I hope that answers your question. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took your code and added to a dummy project to check. I did this for your method

```
required init?( coder aDecoder: NSCoder ) {
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
// removed the load from nib and setup tableview
}
```

In my case I did the following to add the `SubUnitSpinner` view to my parent view. Hope you did the same

```
let aTestView = SubUnitSpinner(frame: CGRectMake(50, 200, 200, 200))
view.addSubview(aTestView)
```

Also double check if you have connected any delegate and datasource from xib. All in all, your code looks fine and I was able to click on it properly. The below are my results that I achieved.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding it programmatically to the UIViewController as you mentioned and then it is clickable (even with xib and tableview setup). I was trying to add it through the storyboard (UIView with Custom Class SubUnitSpinner). Is it not possible to do like that? It seems it would be easier to do the layout all in the storyboard.

Comment: Ah. It would be a lot easier to just write the two lines code than do it from storyboard. Also if you do want to do it from storyboard, I do not see a necessity for creating a custom view. Just drag UIView from objects and create your view with outlets. Anyways, glad it worked. It would be nice if you can accept my answer. :)

Comment: I want to use this view in different parts of the app. That's why I thought it would be better to have a custom view. I guess I'll do it like this, if storyboard way isn't worth it. Any idea what is different when using storyboard?

Comment: If you want to implement this in multiple view then it is good to have a reusable custom view which I see you have already thought of. Storyboard and xib are basically similar as both are used for designing views. So there are no hard and fast rule as to what you have to use. But you can create a UIViewcontroller for this view in one of your story board instead of a xib file and display that UIViewcontroller in other views too. Doing this will reduce the init and setup codes from you custom view and why work hard when you can achieve something so easily.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and all your help. I'll try that then.